# Distinction between series and sum of infinite terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, terminology

Look, we all know that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$ represents an infinity series. Also it represents a sum.

So my question is:

> How can one distinguish between the two ? Is there any difference between the ordinary addition of the terms with the value of the series ?

By ordinary addition, I mean the normal  addition what we done in number system, e.g., $2+3=5$ type.

**My thoughts:** After getting useful information from @JWP_HTX and also searching from various books, I think, the sum (which is used here in a very special sense) of a convergent series is the limit of the sequence of partial sums that is not obtained by ordinary addition. Again the sum gives only a number and it is not capable of being convergent or divergent.

**Note:** I had already made an edit of my question (on the same date of posting) and there is no other additional information with me. So please help and vote to reopen the question so that I can get the correct explanation of my doubts.

Comment: Infinite series and infinite sum are generally synonymous. The idea is that an infinite sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$, if it converges, represents the limit of (well-defined) partial sums $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{k}$.

Comment: What do you  mean by "Also it represents a sum" and by "ordinary addition of the terms"? To me, both just mean the value of the series, but apparently you have something else in mind.

Comment: Okay, I understand @JWP_HTX. But now one thing that make me think about what happens if the series diverges ?

Comment: @nmasanta, by ``ordinary addition," are you trying to make the distinction between infinite and finite sums? In any case, if the series diverges, then that just means that the associated sequence of partial sums does not converge.

Comment: @JWP_HTX: I have mentioned just few seconds ago what I mean by ordinary addition. By the way I think I got your point.

Comment: @nmasanta, ``what we [have] done in algebra" is not exactly an obvious explanation of what you mean by ``ordinary addition." If, however, you are satisfied with your understanding at this point given the above comments, then that is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is yes - there is a difference.  When we consider conditionally convergence series, such as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, we know it converges as written to a finite sum $S$ by Leibnitz' test for convergence.  However, by Riemann's rearrangement theorem, we can actually rearrange the terms of this series to formulate any other finite sum.  So, in a sense, if we define 'normal addition' as adding the series term-by-term in order as written, then we get its sum.  But, the same series summed differently can give us different partial sums.

Answer (score 1):

I learned that the notation $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is shorthand for an ordered pair of sequences, the first being the sequence of "terms" $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ and second, the sequence of "partial sums" $s_1,s_2,\dots,$ where $s_n= a_1+\cdots+a_n.$

Given that, writing something like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/2^n = 1$ doesn't make too much sense. How can a pair of sequences equal the number $1?$ They seem to live in different universes.

Of course, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/2^n = 1$  is defined to mean $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1/2^k=1.$ Kind of an abuse of the equal sign if you ask me. But we do this all the time in mathematics. Writing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = S$ is just too tempting and perfect to avoid. There's no problem with it if we just keep in mind what's happening behind the scenes.